# Cannot pass const data type into a non const function

Tags: c++, constants

Cant pass a const data type into a non const function. After setting the func to type const the error on 
assigning a value in the function will understandably set of an error because its not mutable as its inside
a function of type const.

How can I pass a const varaiable into a non const function by reference, and allow contents of the function 
to be modified?

error C2662: void CarFactory::set_values(Car &) cannot conver this pointer from const Car to Car &

```
 // Tried this
 //Car& newCarData = const_cast<Car&>(myCar);

 const Car& myCar = volvo->GetBuild();
 // Tried this
 //Car& newCarData = const_cast<Car&>(myCar);
 set_values(&myCar);


 void CarFactory::set_values(const Car& myCar){

 // do some assigning here for mutable variables declared in the header

 }
```

Should be able to call this without the error and pass through the data to set_values(). And also modify non const variables set in the header.

Comment: how can you modify something that cannot be modified? You cannot! Why do you make `myCar` a `const` reference when you want to modify it?

Comment: the main focus is I don't want to modify car, but the variables.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: If you have a constant object, all data (member variables) of that object are *also* constant. Otherwise the object wouldn't be constant.

Comment: As other pointed out, you cannot modify a const variable, that's what it's for, and if you need to resort to `const_cast`, you probably have a design error in your code. Can't you return a non-const `Car` from `GetBuild()` ?

Comment: I misread the question before, your error says `void CarFactory::set_values(Car &)` but the code says `void CarFactory::set_values(const Car &)`, are you sure this is the error from the code you posted?

Comment: @aguadoe its a bit hidden but the comment in the method mentions `mutable`

Comment: @user463035818 indeed. It is still a brittle class design. Also the error he gets is because he is taking the address of `myCar` when calling set_values. No conversion is possible from `Car*` to `Car &`

Comment: @aguadoe Mutable by itself is nothing bad, but yes it looks a  bit c-ish ala create the object then set the members, and why the members need to be mutable is also not clear, though a [mcve] would really help to make things more clear

Comment: And `set_values(&myCar);` that's a typo, right?

Comment: From reading the comments I came to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the `Car` object in `set_values` you must pass it a non-const reference. But that means that your `volvo->GetBuild()` must return a non-const reference too.

Answer (score -1):

Solution below, not great but works for this. Backdoor pointer if you will.

```
CarFactory* ptr = const_cast<CarFactory*>(this);
```

In the end, I apologise for not having a minimal working version of code in the question. Tried to explain it where if you know consts you might be able to bounce some ideas around. The comments mentioned did support this solution so thank you.

Comment: `const_cast` is not a solution.

Comment: The plug in im working on now works so its a solution. May not follow the best design principles but I wont tamper with existing architecture.

Comment: No, trust me, it really isn't a solution - if a method returns a const-reference, it is not expecting you to `const_cast` it and modify it. Somewhere there is a serious design problem. Perhaps if you gave more details around the code, people could help further.